# Open one QMainWindow from another QMainWindow

Tags: python-3.x, oop, pyqt5

I have problem with understanding how to open one QMainWindow from another. I want second window to open when the button in the first window is pressed. But I don't know how to do this because classes of the windows is written in the different way.

When I try just to import `Main()` class with the second window in the file with first window, second window starts to open when I run the first file and I don't even see the first window

First window:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def openWindow(self):

        blank




    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 400)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 400))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(600, 400))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(self.centralwidget)
        self.splitter.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 20, 260, 371))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.splitter.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.splitter.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.splitter.setObjectName("splitter")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())

        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(260, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        #self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)
        #this is the button by pressing which i want to open second window





        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_2.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_2.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(260, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")



        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_4.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_4.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(260, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")

        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.splitter)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton_3.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton_3.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.pushButton_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(260, 90))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Просмотр базы"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Выдача/Принятие книг"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Внести книги в базу"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Редактировать список \nклассов"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Second window:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
import sys
import sqlite3
import time
import os

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from test2 import Ui_Dialog
from searchdialog import Ui_Dialogg

from edit import Ui_Dialoge


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("booksbase.db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books(title TEXT,subject TEXT,grade INTEGER,author TEXT,year INTEGER, amount INTEGER)")
        self.c.close()

        self.setWindowTitle("Books base")
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)

        file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&File")

        help_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&About")

        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setAlternatingRowColors(False)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(False)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setCascadingSectionResizes(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(False)
        header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        header.setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(6, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(3, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(4, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(5, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        header.setSectionResizeMode(3, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QTableWidget.NoEditTriggers)


        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(("Заголовок", "Предмет", "Класс", "Автор","Год", "Колличество"))

        self.tableWidget.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.print)

        toolbar = QToolBar()
        toolbar.setMovable(False)
        self.addToolBar(toolbar)

        statusbar = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(statusbar)

        btn_ac_adduser = QAction(QIcon("icon/add1.jpg"), "Add Student", self)   #add student icon
        btn_ac_adduser.triggered.connect(self.insert)
        btn_ac_adduser.setStatusTip("Add Student")
        toolbar.addAction(btn_ac_adduser)

        btn_ac_search = QAction(QIcon("icon/s1.png"), "Search", self)  #search icon
        btn_ac_search.triggered.connect(self.search)
        btn_ac_search.setStatusTip("Search User")
        toolbar.addAction(btn_ac_search)



        adduser_action = QAction(QIcon("icon/add1.jpg"),"Insert Student", self)
        adduser_action.triggered.connect(self.insert)
        file_menu.addAction(adduser_action)

        searchuser_action = QAction(QIcon("icon/s1.png"), "Search Student", self)
        searchuser_action.triggered.connect(self.search)
        file_menu.addAction(searchuser_action)



        about_action = QAction(QIcon("icon/i1.png"),"Developer", self)  #info icon
        about_action.triggered.connect(self.about)
        help_menu.addAction(about_action)

    def loaddata(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect("booksbase.db")
        query = "SELECT * FROM books"
        result = self.connection.execute(query)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row_number, column_number, QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))
        self.connection.close()

    def insert(self):
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialog()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        Dialog.exec_()
        print("now")
        self.loaddata()


    def search(self):
        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialogg()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog)
        Dialog.exec_()




    def print(self):
        row = self.tableWidget.currentRow()
        col = self.tableWidget.item(row,0)
        title = col.text()

        col = self.tableWidget.item(row,1)
        subject = col.text()

        col = self.tableWidget.item(row,2)
        grade = col.text()

        col = self.tableWidget.item(row,3)
        author = col.text()

        col = self.tableWidget.item(row,4)
        year = col.text()

        col = self.tableWidget.item(row,5)
        amount = col.text()

        print(title, subject, grade, author, year, amount)

        Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_Dialoge()
        ui.setupUi(Dialog, title, subject, grade, author, year, amount)
        Dialog.exec_()
        self.loaddata()




app = QApplication(sys.argv)
if(QDialog.Accepted == True):
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    window.loaddata()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the last lines of the second window file (from `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` to the end)?

Comment: @musicamante , Thank you! Deleting these lines was a solution!

Comment: Good. I've added an actual answer, better explaining what was going on, remember to mark it as accepted since it solves your problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems resides in the fact that the file you are importing for the second window tries to run its last block:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
if(QDialog.Accepted == True):
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    window.loaddata()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When a file (module) is imported, all of its executable statements are processed; in simple terms, everything that's "outside" a `def` is executed, including the module's own imports, function *calls*, try/except blocks, for/while loops, and all statements within any class definition.

Since you're checking against `QDialog.Accepted` (which is a constant), the statement is obviously true, then that if block is executed, resulting in the window being initialized and shown.

Remove that block from the second file and it will work as expected.

Two notes about that code, anyway:

- there should exist one and only one QApplication instance for each PyQt based program; the above code could actually crash in most cases because of that;
- as said before, QDialog.Accepted is a constant, and it's value is `1`, so that `if` statements doesn't make much sense (it would have been the same as `if True == True:`); that constant, along with its opposite `QDialog.Rejected`, is normally used only when checked against the return value of a [QDialog.exec()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#exec) call.